# Как проверить начинается ли имя файла с заданной строки?

Tags: php

Например "open_tag" и "open" вернёт true

Comment: strpos  см. в документации  или str_starts_with (php8)

Answer (score 0):

`str_starts_with('Исходная строка', 'С чего начинается')`